# Intent Filter for multiple MIME-types

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter

My question is how to properly specify an `Activity` handling different MIME-types in Manifest file. I'm trying to create an `Activity` that would handle different archives, so I add it to Manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.ArchiveActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_archive" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/gzip" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-tar" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/java-archive" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Unfortunately, this only works for .zip files. When I try to open a .jar archive, for example, from another application, it tells me that it's unable to find a proper application. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** As it turns out, Android can't understand last three MIME-types, so I presume there is no way to open .jar files in Android using Intents.

Comment: i would define an intent-filter for each mimetype

Comment: @njzk2, This also doesn't work, same behavior observed.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and then accept your answer. That way this question doesn't show up in the "unanswered" list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Late for the party, but in case if someone on the internet will go around this thread.

In 2022, according to documentation:
[android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

> You can create a filter that includes more than one instance of `<action>`, `<data>`, or `<category>`. If you do, you need to be certain that the component can handle any and all combinations of those filter elements.

So You don't have to create separate intent-filter for each MIME type, for me this code works:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The question's code does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/gzip" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-tar" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/java-archive" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: i think this is what he was trying to avoid