# Android Getting files from dropbox

Tags: java, android, file, x509certificate, intentfilter

I need to receive files from the "share" button of dropbox or skydrive. I am using the intent-filter in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

So far, I can send images from the Gallery to my app but I cannot send anything from dropbox to my app to start the activity. Any recomendations? I need to be able to get .cer, .pdf and .key files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dropbox has it's own Android SDK that you can utilize.  Take a look here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android

The documentation gives examples of how to both upload and download files.  Here's the download file docs:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#downloading

Comment: The SDK/API won't help with setting up an intent filter for action.SEND.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your usage of multiple mimeTypes within a single intent-filter element.  According to what I've seen/read, only the first mimeType ends up working when you do that. If you define a an intent-filter per mimeType it should work.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139094/intent-filter-for-multiple-mime-types) for an example.